# How to assign a db user to multiple databases at once from cPanel?

Tags: cpanel, whm

Inside cPanel, I can create a database and I can assign a specific db user to a specific database.

But what if I have like 100 databases. How can I assign the same user to all of the databases created in my cPanel account?